# Rspec testing ActiveAdmin create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, activeadmin

My rails application has model `Institution` that only an `AdminUser` can create. My `app/admin/institution.rb` file looks like this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Institution do

  permit_params :name, :email

  index do
    id_column
    %W(name email).each do |field|
      column field.to_sym
    end
    actions
  end

  form do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :name
      f.input :email
      f.actions
    end

  end

end
```

and the corresponding route for creating an institution is `POST /admin/institutions`.

Is there a simple way to test this route/action in rspec? There are very few resources online about testing ActiveAdmin. All I could find was [this](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/wiki/Testing-your-ActiveAdmin-resources-with-RSpec), [this](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/wiki/testing-your-activeadmin-controllers-with-rspec) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18240851/write-controller-and-feature-specs-for-activeadmin-using-rspec), the last of which seemed closest to what I am looking for, but not exactly.

I just want a way to test the `POST /admin/institutions` endpoint, passing it only the two required params (name and email). However the following rspec test fails:

```
describe Admin::InstitutionsController, :type => :controller do

  before(:each) do
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:admin_user)
    sign_in @user
  end

  it 'creates an institution' do
    post :create, name: "test_name", email: "test@email.com"
    expect(Institution.all.count).to eq(1)
  end

end
```

No institution is being created but I do not get any errors. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

-Greg

Comment: `expect{post :create, name: "test_name", email: "test@email.com"}.to change{Institution.count}.by(1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try namespacing the parameters with the `institution` key. In most resource
based forms in Rails the form fields are grouped by the model's name. Give the following a try:

```
it 'creates an institution' do
  post :create, institution: { name: "test_name", email: "test@email.com" }
  expect(Institution.all.count).to eq(1)
end
```

The reason is how the form renders those two fields as text inputs (check the HTML source). The field's names should be:

- `institution[name]`
- `institution[email]`